# Fragment in Viewpager only refreshing when it's open from fragments next to it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

So basically i have 4 fragments I'm currently working on second. I have some weird situation here. When app started it open fragment on position 1 then if I navigate to fragment 2 via tabs on top fragment 2 will update, then if I open fragment 3 from fragment 2 and return to fragment 2 from fragment 3 it will also update. But if I choose to open fragment 4 and then return to fragment 2 it won't refresh. This is method that I'm calling to refresh fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        loadEvents();
    }
    Log.d("TAG", "VISIBLE");
}
```

in LoadEvents there are few recyclerview setting their adapters. Nothing speciall

Comment: Sorry, your problem is that you do not update fragment 2 returning from the fragment 4 or your goal is not to refresh fragment 2 returning from the fragment 4?

Comment: It's my problem I want to update it when returning from fragment 4

Comment: How do you mean fragment gets updated? Viewpager will load adjacent fragments e.g. if you are on page 1 - it will create fragment 1 and adjacent fragment 2. When you swipe to second page, it will just show already created fragment 2 and will create adjacent fragment 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because when you call fragment 3 and when you return to the fragment 2 you use `.replace` , instead when you go to the fragment 4 you use `.add` and to return to the fragment 2 `.show`.

looks at the differences between:

- add
- replace
- show

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html